# C4droid + gcc sdl -> sdl_opengl.h error

Tags: android, c++, gcc, opengl-es, sdl

I'm developing games with c4droid on android with sdl,gcc plugin.
All works great and fine...

But Now i need a 3D graphic lib for my game and i was looking for it and found the answer: **openGL**

But when i try to type:

```
#include "SDL/Sdl_opengl.h"
```

it says: `gl/gl.h not found or gl/glu.h not found`

The example `NativeActivity` uses `open_gl` too but the are follow path

```
INCLUDE GLES/GL.H
INCLUDE EGL/EGL.H
...
```

But I can't understand the code and its all with licence etc...

how can I use sdl_opengl.h in c4droid

I have install opengl es 2.0 demo but its only a app that show 6 samples , no code , no libs, no folders :(

Answer (score -1):

**GL/gl.h** is not available, as Android does not support OpenGL. However it does support **OpenGL ES** and you should be able to find **GLES/gl.h**, **GLES2/gl2.h**  and **GLES3/gl3.h** in Android NDK.

On older platform levels, **gl2.h (ES2.0)** and/or **gl3 (ES3.0)** may be unavailable.

In NDK you can also find hello-gl2,  native-activity and san-angeles samples, with source code, that show howto use OGL ES on Android (without SDL).

On SDL you propably dont want to use SDL_opengl.h: just include GLES*/gl.h manually, use SDL only for surface and GL context setup. See: [this link](http://www.ciaranmccormack.com/sdl-2-0-on-android-using-the-ndk-opengl-es-2-0-and-c-11/)

Comment: The link is dead.